# Retrieving Paperclip attributes for Cocoon in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, cocoon-gem

I'm trying to use the Cocoon gem with the Paperclip gem in Rails. My object has_many :attachments, and attachments has_attached_file :attachment_file.

I would like the fields to be rendered as plain text as well as attachment_file.name to be shown in the partial.

The objects get rendered like this:

```
          =f.fields_for :attachments do |attachment|
            =render 'attachment_fields2', f: attachment
```

Here is the partial that gets rendered from inside the "object" form:

```
.row.nested-fields.col-xs-12
tr
    .col-xs-12
        .form-inline
            .col-xs-12.no-padding
                =f.file_field :attachment_file, class:"col-xs-4"
                =attachment.name, class:"col-xs-7"//////this line throws an error
                =link_to_remove_association f do
                    |<i class="fa fa-times col-xs-1"></i>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `f.name`? And also please post your complete error log.

Comment: What do you mean by `attachment_file.name` to be shown in the partial?

Comment: @Pavan  from paperclip's homepage 

"Paperclip will wrap up to four attributes (all prefixed with that attachment's name, so you can have multiple attachments per model if you wish) and give them a friendly front end. These attributes are:

<attachment>_file_name
<attachment>_file_size
<attachment>_content_type
<attachment>_updated_at"

I would like to have that file name in the form but not attached to a field.

Comment: @Pavan f.name doesn't render anything either.  The error says: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' ...ynamic((f.name, class:"col-xs-7"), false, "\n ... ... ^

Comment: I understood. Try `attachment.attachment_file_name` If doesn't work try `f.attachment_file_name`

Comment: If the above both doesn't work, try `params[:attachment][:attachment_file_name]`

Comment: Any luck with the suggestions?

Comment: @Pavan I haven't had much luck with your suggestions but I managed to get it to work by using attachment.object.attachment_file.name rather than attachment.attachment_file.name.  It was thanks to your comments that I can across that answer so if you type it out I'll mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Did `f.object.attachment_file.name` worked or `f.object.attachment_file_name`?

Comment: @Pavan I'm not sure what you mean, inside =f.fields_for :rfq_attachments do |attachment|
i added attachment.object.attachment_file.name

Comment: Okay. I can't post my answer because i don't know how it worked. You can post the solution as your answer and you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @Pavan Okay, thank you for the help.  Best of luck in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out I can get the attributes from inside the form builder using .object

Instead of

```
=attachment.name, class:"col-xs-7"
```

I did

```
=attachment.object.name
```